# Word match in group collection

Tags: regex, wildcard

For successful parsing I need to meet two conditions. I have following pattern currently being used for multiple word matches at first condition-1:

```
^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\bid\b).*$
```

On **condition-2** I would like this pattern to work in combination of another pattern.

**(?=.*\bfor|of|from\b)***(?=.\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\bid\b)

so if `(?=.*\bfor|of|from\b)` matches on its own the user will get error that you have forgot to enter something (i.e. things id etc)

and if this can also work in reverse order:

so if `(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\bid\b)` matches on its own the user will get error saying you have missed (?=.*\bfor|of|from\b)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It might help if you could edit the question so that it includes a bulleted list of your requirements, along with some samples of the data you are parsing.

Comment: Hi tmoore, I have tried to make it simple I am sure if it makes any sense now. Thanks

Comment: The question makes more sense now. I think you'll want to use a conditional regex if possible. What language are you programming in? If .NET, Perl, or Python, you can use conditional regex. This might make code handling a little easier.

Comment: Here's a link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html. Forgot to add it earlier.

Comment: I am using .Net. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a programming language.  Wouldn't it make more sense to take advantage of that?  How about:

```
Match has_for_of_from = Regex.Match(input, @"\b(for|of|from)\b");
Match has_good_thing = Regex.Match(input, @"\b(?:good|thing|item)s?\b");
Match has_id = Regex.Match(input, @"\bid\b");
if (has_for_of_from && not (has_good_thing && has_id)) {
  // error about missing items/id
}
if (has_good_thing && has_id && not has_for_from) {
  // error about missing for/of/from
}
```

I moved the optional `s` outside the alternation (making it easier to read but still doing the same thing).  I wasn't sure from the description whether the logic is exactly what you wanted (should that first conditional say `has_for && not (has_good || has_id)`?), but I'm sure you can figure it out from here.

You'd need a pretty messy regex to do this in just one match, and it wouldn't necessarily suggest which condition triggered the issue, so you won't have an informative error message.

Disclaimer:  I do not know [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), so my syntax may be slightly off.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I will give it a go and let you know if it works.